# C# - Use a delegate to run a method at the same time every hour

Tags: c#, events, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run a code in given time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972964/run-a-code-in-given-time-interval)

I have a method that runs on the hour. I am currently doing this like so:

```
while (true)
{
        string rightNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm");

        if (rightNow == "00")
        {
            RunMyMethod();
        }
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

I have been reliably informed by a friend that I'm an idiot (and generally a bad person), and that I should be using events and delegates to do this instead. I get that, outside the scope of any methods I need declare a delegate with the same return type as my method, and with the same input parameters like so:

```
public delegate void MyMethodsDelegate();
```

Then, when I want to use my delegate I instantiate it in the same way I instanciate a class like so:

```
MyMethodsDelegate foobar = new MyMethodsDelegate(RunMyMethod);
```

Then I can invoke my delegate like so:

```
foobar.Invoke();
```

Ok so I have my delegate setup, how about the event? The event I want to create is 'It's x o'clock', then every time it's x o'clock this kicks off my delegate

Also, am I setting up my delegate correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use Windows Task Schedular (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of using the delegate create an exe and use the task schedular?

Comment: Your friend sounds like a nice guy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972964/run-a-code-in-given-time-interval

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class which executes a delegate asynchronously and raises the [Elapsed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) when given time interval is elapsed. I would strongly recommend you reading MSDN remarks part for the Timer class, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx).

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new Timer(60 * 60 * 100);
```

Case 1: Subscribe to anonymous method

```
timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
    {
        // callback code here
    };
```

Case 2: Subscribe to explicitly defined delegate

```
ElapsedEventHandler handler = (s, e) =>
    {
        // callback code here
    };
timer.Elapsed += handler;
```

Case 3: Subscribe to the existing method

```
timer.Elapsed += this.OnHourElapsed;
private void OnHourElapsed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // callback code here
}
```

Then finally just start a timer

```
timer.Start();
```