# Android: How can I reliably detect every minute in time?

Tags: android, timer

I need a reliable way to monitor minute-ticks in an Android app. This thread (in C#) [.NET, event every minute (on the minute). Is a timer the best option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329900/net-event-every-minute-on-the-minute-is-a-timer-the-best-option) says that creating a timer that ticks every second and within that event, checking if a minute has gone by, adds negligible overhead to a C# application.

Is the same approach in Android feasible? Or are there other ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a Timer that fires at a given time:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
long fireAt = System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000;
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(),new Date(fireAt));
```

Comment: That works perfect for *one* call, but if you want to have a **reliable** tick **every** minute, you will end up with a very noticeable drifting scheduling timers at every run.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) View.