# System.Threading.Timer call drifts a couple seconds every day

Tags: c#, time, windows-services, timer

I have a service that is always running, it has a timer to perform a particular action every day at 2AM.

```
TimeSpan runTime = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0); // 2 AM
TimeSpan timeToFirstRun = runTime - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

if (timeToFirstRun.TotalHours < 0)
{
    timeToFirstRun += TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0);
}

_dailyNodalRunTimer = new Timer(
    RunNodalDailyBatch,
    null,
    timeToFirstRun,
    TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0)); //repeat event daily
```

That initialization code is called once when the service first starts, over the past few days I have logged when the Timer has fired:

```
2011-05-21 02:00:01.580
2011-05-22 02:00:03.840
...
2011-05-31 02:00:25.227
2011-06-01 02:00:27.423
2011-06-02 02:00:29.847
```

As you can see its drifting by 2 seconds every day, getting farther and farther from when it was supposed to fire(at 2 AM).

Am I using it wrong or is this Timer not designed to be accurate? I could recreate the timer each day, or have it fire at some small interval and repeatedly check if I want to perform the action, but that seems kind of hacky.

**EDIT**

I tried using System.Timers.Timer and it appears to have the same issue. The reseting the Interval is because you cant schedule the initial time before the first tick in System.Timers.Timer like you can in System.Threading.Timer

```
int secondsInterval = 5;

double secondsUntilRunFirstRun = secondsInterval - (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds % secondsInterval);
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(secondsUntilRunFirstRun * 1000.0);
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));

        if (timer.Interval != (secondsInterval * 1000.0))
            timer.Interval = secondsInterval * 1000.0;
    };
timer.Start();
```

Produce the following times, you can see how they are drifting slightly:

```
06:47:40.020
06:47:45.035
06:47:50.051
...
06:49:40.215
06:49:45.223
06:49:50.232
```

So I guess the best approach really is to just reschedule the timer in the tick handler? The following produces a tick at a regular interval within ~15 milliseconds

```
double secondsUntilRunFirstRun = secondsInterval - (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds % secondsInterval);

var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(secondsUntilRunFirstRun * 1000.0);
timer.AutoReset = false;
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));

    timer.Interval = (secondsInterval - (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds % secondsInterval)) * 1000.0;
};
timer.Start();


06:51:45.009
06:51:50.001
...
06:52:50.011
06:52:55.013
06:53:00.001
```

Comment: Is the function taking 2 seconds?

Comment: The timer is just kicking off the event, does it really wait for the worker thread to finish before rescheduling the event? I'm not sure how long the function takes exactly, it could be around 2 seconds

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the windows scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the timers in the .NET Framework will be accurate. There are too many variables in play. If you want a more accurate timer then take a look at [multimedia timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743609%28VS.85%29.aspx). I have never used them over longer durations, but I suspect they are still substantially more accurate than the BCL timers.

But, I see no reason that would prohibit you from using the `System.Threading.Timer` class. Instead of specifying `TimeSpan.FromDays(1)` use `Timeout.Infinite` to prevent periodic signaling. You will then have to restart the timer, but you can specify 23:59:58 or 1.00:00:05 for the `dueTime` parameter depending on what you calculate the next due time to be to have signal at 2:00a.

By the way, the `System.Timers.Timer` will do no better than `System.Threading.Timer`. The reason is because the former actually uses the later behind the scenes anyway. `System.Timers.Timer` just adds a few handy features like auto resetting and marshaling the execution of the `Elapsed` onto an `ISynchronizeInvoke` hosted thread (usually a UI thread).

Answer (score 4):

Don't let timer inaccuracies accumulate. Use the RTC to calculate how many ms remain until the timeout time.  Sleep/setInterval to half this time. When the timer fires/sleep returns, use the RTC again to recalculate the interval left and set interval/sleep again to half-life.  Repeat this loop until the remaining interval is less than 50ms. Then CPU loop on the RTC until the desired time is exceeded. Fire the event.

Rgds,
Martin

Answer (score 3):

I think you've already realized this but if you want something to fire at a certain time of day (2AM) you'd be better off with a dedicated thread that sleeps, periodically wakes up and looks to see if it's time to run yet.  A sleep around 100 milliseconds would be appropriate and would burn virtually no CPU.

Another approach would be that after you've done your daily work, you compute when to next fire based on 2AM tomorrow - DateTime.Current, etc.  This may still not be as accurate as you want (I'm not sure) but at least the drift won't get worse and worse and worse.

Answer (score 2):

If you need accurate timing, you'll need [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class.

Also see this question: [.NET, event every minute (on the minute). Is a timer the best option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329900/net-event-every-minute-on-the-minute-is-a-timer-the-best-option)

Answer (score 1):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx):

> System.Threading.Timer is a simple,
>   lightweight timer ... For server-based timer functionality, you might consider using [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), which raises events and has additional features.

You can also move it to [Windows Task Scheduler](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=windows%20task%20sceduler)