# Method that runs when a new minute starts

Tags: c#, timer

I have a function that runs every minute:

```
var waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
    waitHandle,
    // Method to execute
    (state, timeout) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " START");
        ..some stuff
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " END");
    },
    null,
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    false
);
```

This code executes well, but sample output is:

```
2016-08-16 18:45:55 START
2016-08-16 18:45:55 END
2016-08-16 18:46:55 START
2016-08-16 18:46:55 END
```

(or whatever second it happens to be at at the time of calling) 
I would like it to run like this:

```
2016-08-16 18:45:00 START
2016-08-16 18:45:00 END
2016-08-16 18:46:00 START
2016-08-16 18:46:00 END
```

So I want this function to run every minute, but when the seconds are at 0. How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329900/net-event-every-minute-on-the-minute-is-a-timer-the-best-option?rq=1

Comment: @serhiyb - I was wondering if there's a way of editing my code and the RegisterWaitForSingleObject method to do the same thing

Comment: [edit] your question to make it clear what you want, and why the solution you have is not working for you.

Comment: what's wrong with the code right now?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I edited it

Comment: @Rakitić I added what's wrong with it

Comment: See the marked duplicate for the answer. Note the advice offered as part of that Q&A that points out that you will _never_ be guaranteed execution exactly on the minute mark. You can get very close, but Windows isn't a real-time OS and can't provide real-time scheduling. Note also that your method of scheduling -- waiting on a wait handle with a timeout -- is a bit odd. .NET has a variety of timer implementations that would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the problem is the initial offset you have to add to your code. It can be done easily, based on the second answer from the question linked by serhiyb:

```
void Register(AutoResetEvent waitHandle, TimeSpan timeout, 
    WaitOrTimerCallback callback, bool once)
{
    ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(waitHandle, callback, null, timeout, once);
}

void Callback(object state, bool isTimeout)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " START");
    //..some stuff
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " END");
}
```

And then:

```
var waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

Register(
    waitHandle,
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60 - DateTime.Now.Second), //initial offset
    (state, isTimeout) =>
    {
        Callback(state, isTimeout);
        Register(waitHandle, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), Callback, false);
    },
    true);
```