# "timer + Task.Run" vs "while loop + Task.Delay" in asp.net core hosted service

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, task, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have a requirement that background service should run `Process` method every day at 0:00 a.m.

So, one of my team member wrote the following code:

```
public class MyBackgroundService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private Timer _timer;

    public MyBackgroundService(ILogger<MyBackgroundService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        TimeSpan firstCall = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1).Subtract(DateTime.Now);

        Action action = () =>
        {
            Task.Delay(firstCall).Wait();

            Process();

            _timer = new Timer(
                ob => Process(),
                null,
                TimeSpan.Zero,
                interval
            );
        };

        Task.Run(action);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task Process()
    {
        try
        {
            // perform some database operations
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, e.Message);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This code works as expected. But I don't like that it synchronously waits till calling `Process` first time, so a thread is blocked and not performing any useful work (correct me if I am wrong).

I could make an action async and await in it like this:

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // code omitted for brevity

    Action action = async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(firstCall);

        await Process();
        
        // code omitted for brevity
}
```

But I am not sure that using `Task.Run` is a good thing here as `Process` method should perform some I/O operations (query DB and insert some data), and because it's not recommended to use `Task.Run` in ASP.NET environment.

I refactored `StartAsync` as follows:

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
    TimeSpan firstDelay = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1).Subtract(DateTime.Now);

    await Task.Delay(firstDelay);

    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Process();

        await Task.Delay(interval, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And this allows me not to use timer in `MyBackgroundService` at all.

Should I use the first approach with "timer + Task.Run" or the second one with "while loop + Task.Delay"?

Comment: I'm not going to comment on "should I", but instead point out a minor ... flaw? issue? If `Process` take 5 minutes, your schedule will be skewed by 5 minutes on every execution. That is, until your service is restarted.

Comment: Why first delay is even needed? Timer already supports parameter indicating a delay before the first run. Then you can remove everything except timer creation.

Comment: Or you could just use a library designed to do exactly this? https://codeburst.io/schedule-background-jobs-using-hangfire-in-net-core-2d98eb64b196

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, This is a real significant flaw. Thanks you have noticed this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `while` loop approach is simpler and safer. Using the [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer) class has two hidden gotchas:

1. Subsequent events can potentially invoke the attached event handler in an ovelapping manner.
2. Exceptions thrown inside the handler are swallowed, and *this behavior is subject to change in future releases of the .NET Framework.* (from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer#remarks))

Your current `while` loop implementation can be improved in various ways though:

1. Reading the `DateTime.Now` multiple times during a `TimeSpan` calculation may produce unexpected results, because the `DateTime` returned by `DateTime.Now` can be different each time. It is preferable to store the `DateTime.Now` in a variable, and use the stored value in the calculations.
2. Checking the condition `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` in the `while` loop could result to inconsistent cancellation behavior, if you also use the same token as an argument of the `Task.Delay`. Skipping this check completely is simpler and consistent. This way cancelling the token will always produce an `OperationCanceledException` as a result.
3. Ideally the duration of the `Process` should not affect the scheduling of the next operation. One way to do it is to create the `Task.Delay` task before starting the `Process`, and `await` it after the completion of the `Process`. Or you can just recalculate the next delay based on the current time. This has also the advantage that the scheduling will be adjusted automatically in case of a system-wise time change.

Here is my suggestion:

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    TimeSpan scheduledTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(0); // midnight
    TimeSpan minimumIntervalBetweenStarts = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);

    while (true)
    {
        var scheduledDelay = scheduledTime - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

        while (scheduledDelay < TimeSpan.Zero)
            scheduledDelay += TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

        await Task.Delay(scheduledDelay, cancellationToken);

        var delayBetweenStarts =
            Task.Delay(minimumIntervalBetweenStarts, cancellationToken);

        await ProcessAsync();

        await delayBetweenStarts;
    }
}
```

The reason for the `minimumIntervalBetweenStarts` is to protect from very dramatic system-wise time changes.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. You said that I read `DateTime.Now` multiple times. But I use `DateTime.Now` only once when I calculate `firstDelay`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DmitryStepanov my pleasure! Yes, the `DateTime.Today` also implies a reading of the `DateTime.Now` property ([source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/datetime.cs.html#013b44cc4074ffd2)).

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias Hi there, Would you mind sharing how you would amend this if you needed to run ProcessAsync() every second (or less)? Appreciate any guidance you can offer.

Comment: Hi @ledragon. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval/62724908#62724908 "Run async method regularly with specified interval") is close to what you want (the `PeriodicAsync` method).

Comment: Instead of calculating the intervals manually, it is also possible to use a specialized library like the [Cronos](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos). You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73951786/how-to-run-10-long-running-functions-repeatedly-at-specific-times-avoiding-over/73968485#73968485 "How to run 10 long-running functions repeatedly at specific times, avoiding overlapping execution?") for an implementation of a timer (`CronosTimer`) that is based on Cronos.